# Two variable polynomials that behave like Lagrange polynomials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Let us consider different points   $z_i=(x_i,y_i)$  in the plane where $i=1,\cdots n$.

> Q Do there exist two variable polynomials $P_i(x,y)$ with minimal degree such that $P_i(z_j)=\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: This is clearly impossible unless all the $x_i$ are distinct and all the $y_i$ are distinct, in which case $$P_i(x, y) = \frac{\prod_{j \neq i}(x - x_i)(y - y_i)}{\prod_{j \neq i}(x_j - x_i)(y_j - y_i)}$$ Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Of course they exist: there exist some polynomials with prescribed values, among them there is a polynomial of minimal degree. Maybe you wanted to ask something different?

Answer (score 2):

To get polynomials $P_i(x,y)$ such that $P_i(z_j)=\delta_{ij}$, you can write
$$P_i(x,y)=\frac{\prod\limits_{j:j\ne i}[(x-x_j)^2+(y-y_j)^2]}{\prod\limits_{j:j\ne i}[(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2]}.$$

So, polynomials of minimal degree with such an interpolation property do exist.

Comment: That is a great idea. How can we sure concerning with degree minimality?

Comment: @AliBagheri : Your question was "Do there exist two variable polynomials $P_i(x,y)$ with minimal degree such that $P_i(z_j)=\delta_{ij}$?" The answer above shows that the set of all polynomials $P_i(x,y)$ such that $P_i(z_j)=\delta_{ij}$ is nonempty. Selecting a polynomial of the minimal degree in this set of polynomials thus provides an affirmative answer to your question. Of course, one can be interested in an explicit construction of such a minimal-degree polynomial -- but that would be a question different from the one you asked.